# get paypal account detail of client by api

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

How can I get client name post code and address details by `api in paypal`. please guide me, I have successfully done checkout but I don't want to charge to my client I'm just want to get there address detail by `api`.

*Please let me know if you have any suggestion.*

Answer (score -2):

First of all use developer account during test phase.

Regarding your question on PayPal API, see there official documentation listed here specifying your answer already: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/

Comment: Oops, we can’t find that page!